# The Open University (Open Learn) Learn to code for data analysis

Tags: python, syntax-error, jupyter

So I am enrolled in a free OpenLearn course 'Learn to code for data analysis' with The Open University.

The course teaches basic coding techniques using Python and does this via Jupyter Exercise books.

Attached is an image of question 1 from the 'Practise Quiz', that is available to complete after finishing the exercises, and my answer based on what is taught in the Jupyter Exercise books.

Bear in mind at no point have they indicated that our answers is the quiz should be in any other format that what we have already learnt in the exercises.

I have some experience with C++, C# excel and VBA so something as basic as adding together 2 different sets of variables and the multiplying them together isn't THIS difficult.

I've also attached an image of the error I get (seems to be a Syntax Error) but this early into the course they have not explained anything regarding Syntax Errors or how to fix them.

I just have no idea how they want this answer written or what they expect from me.

Has anyone had any experience with this course of similar issue?

[image: question + my answer]
[image: response / error]

Comment: Since we now have a correct answer, would you mind accepting it? Also, could you please try to convert your screenshot here into formatted text, to the extent possible? That way other people might find it easier to find your question via the search interface here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
dataA = 2
dataB = 3
dataC = 4
dataD = 5
answer  = (dataA+dataB)*(dataC+dataD)
```

I think the problem lies in that there is no variable assigned to the calculation. (Even though python accepts it as correct syntax. the program you are using might not be able to see that you have done the calculation because it is not saved)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've already tried defining the result as a variable and it didn't work. I copied and pasted your suggestion (just to double check) and I get the same result. As a complete shot in the dark I wrote it out just using the values (no variables) so (2+3)*(4+5) and a different 'result' displayed at the bottom of the screen. Indicating that I got something right ad there was a green tick but then there were 4 red crosses... these were shown next to 4 different sets of numbers displayed how the original 4 values were. Something tells me this question isn't complete...

Comment: and it's actually looking for what I did (2+3)*(4+5) but with 4 different data sets but it only gives me the original data set of 2,3,4 & 5

Comment: they are checking with different data sets that means they might be expecting variables as inputs. That's when your first test case run, and other three showed red wrong marks. try taking dataA, dataB, dataC and dataD as inputs and then result the expression.

Comment: Hi Naazneen, I just typed in (dataA+dataB) * (dataC+dataD)  and I got all 4 tick marks! I would call you a genius for suggesting it but that WAS NOT CLEAR on their website AT ALL that they would be providing the data AFTER writing the code.... is it me or was that not made clear?

Comment: @Craig1990 I think the issue is that in your code you are overwriting the values of these 4 variables before the final expression. So when the test script checks your code, you always get the same result (`45`).

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the example they give you. Try this

```
(dataA + dataB) * (dataC + dataD)
```

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @UsamaAbdulrehman According to the other comment thread, this does seem to solve the issue. (Hence, I hope OP can accept this as the correct answer.)